# Heroku Application Error (Django web App)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I am new in development and I don't understand all of these errors please help me.
I am stuck in this code for more than five days from now I don't understand the reason of this error! Deploy are done but now application error.

Heroku gives me an Application error

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail**


2021-10-01T19:55:11.337603+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337603+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-01 19:55:11 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337603+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337604+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337604+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337605+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337605+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337606+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337613+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337613+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337613+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337613+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337614+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/ecom/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337615+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337616+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337616+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337617+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337618+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337618+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337619+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/ecom/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337622+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337622+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337771+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-01 19:55:11 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.337790+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-01 19:55:11 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.417980+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-01T19:55:11.417987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418243+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418251+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418381+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418383+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418481+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418488+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418632+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418689+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418690+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418690+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418690+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418691+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 642, in kill_worker
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418861+00:00 app[web.1]: os.kill(pid, sig)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418886+00:00 app[web.1]: ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418888+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418889+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418889+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418896+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-01T19:55:11.418904+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419043+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419051+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419133+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419142+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419239+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419317+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419395+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419403+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419518+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419526+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 390, in stop
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419650+00:00 app[web.1]: self.kill_workers(sig)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419657+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 632, in kill_workers
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419831+00:00 app[web.1]: self.kill_worker(pid, sig)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.419839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 647, in kill_worker
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420026+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.tmp.close()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420033+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/workertmp.py", line 55, in close
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420107+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._tmp.close()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420114+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420211+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420356+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-10-01T19:55:11.420385+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-10-01T19:55:11.546484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-01T19:55:11.659826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-10-01T19:55:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-10-01T19:55:24.350609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ecomninjas.herokuapp.com request_id=2af3e8c6-cadf-416a-ad16-ce3175819ac3 fwd="157.40.160.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https



**how can I fix this? need help!**
```

ignore this
An error is an action which is inaccurate or incorrect. In some usages, an error is synonymous with a mistake. In statistics, "error" refers to the difference between the value which has been computed and the correct value. An error could result in failure or in a deviation from the intended performance or behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

It means you haven't installed this package
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#settings-py-changes

> pip install django-heroku

Be sure to add django-heroku to your requirements.txt file as well.

Comment: where exactly put django_heroku.settings(locals()) in setting.py

Comment: You shoud add to the bottom of settings.py @Arijit

Comment: yes I did and recreate the requirements.txt but same error occurs